# rails 2.3, link_to in mailer view,

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-2

I have setup of mailer that is working perfectly. 
I want to send a link in mail body so in view of mailer i am doing the following:

```
<%= link_to "somesite","http://www.somesite.com" %>
```

but in delivered email it appears as following:

```
<a href="http://www.somesite.com/">somesite</a>
```

Please let me know if i am missing something. 
i have already changed the filename message.erb to message.html.erb, but that didn't helped.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but what behavior were you expecting? You passed two arguments to `#link_to` in the right order: the text you want inside the hyperlink tags and the `href` attribute you're looking for. Rails appears to have generated the appropriate HTML.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this a while back.  I believe the convention you need to follow for naming your templates is `message.text.html.erb`.  The docs [here](http://apidock.com/rails/v2.3.2/ActionMailer/Base) seem to suggest I'm remembering this right.

The reason for this is that the mime type of the email is inferred from the filename.  If you have `message.text.plain.erb` then ActionMailer should send out a multipart email with a plain text and html portion.  You may need to do something extra to make it do that, but I *think* you don't, if you have both templates.